# How to convert images low width 200

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have the code below for image conversion.

I have a directory with many images, I would like to convert all images that the width was less than 200 pixel.

Regardless of the extension, `jpg`, `gif` or `png`

```
find . -iname \*.jpg -exec convert -verbose -resize 200x140! "{}" "{}" \;
```

Comment: Is it working for .jpgs?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this - or something very close to it - so make a backup first!

```
find . \( -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.png -o -iname \*.gif \) \
   -exec bash -c '[ $(identify -format %w "$0" ) -lt 200 ] && convert "$0" -resize 200x140\! "$0"' {} \;
```

That says... *"find, starting in the current directory (`.`), any files whose names end, in a case-insensitive fashion (`-iname`), in `JPG`, `PNG` or `GIF` and start a new `bash` shell for each one. Once inside the shell, get the width of the file and if it is less than 200 pixels, execute the `convert` command to resize the file to 200x140, ignoring aspect ratio."*

Answer (score 0):

The "first" part in there is: acquiring the width of all images in that folder. And if I read your question correctly, that is where you have problems with; thus you can look into the *identify* command coming with ImageMagick. It works like this

```
identify -format "%wx%h" pic.jpg
```

See [here](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-format) for handling formatting. As soon as you got your list of "width matching" files, you should be able to further convert them.